# theory of computation: how can A be the language recognized by machine M1

Tags: theory, finite-automata

This is taken from a theory of computation book:

If the diagram below represents machine M1,

[image]

how can A, the language machine M1 recognizes, be described as:

A = {w| w contains at least one 1 and an even number of 0s follow the last 1}

when the string 011 is accepted by machine M1. 
011 in fact contains at least one 1, but an even number of 0s do not follow the last 1.

Then, isn't it incorrect to say "and even number of 0s follow the last 1"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not (yet) a programming question. As written, it is a question about the theory of computation.

Comment: @RaymondChen where do these posts normally go? It seems that people on stackoverflow have asked non-programming questions on the theory of computation before, which is why I felt it was safe to post

Comment: cs.stackexchange.com is for things like the theory of computation, computer architecture design, formal methods, lambda calculus...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of [natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) contains many even numbers. Working down from very large evens, we finally arrive at: `..., 6, 4, 2, 0`. There are in fact zero 0s after the last 1, which is in that set.